# writning the data into the database using xml file in groovy

Tags: groovy

```
import groovy.sql.Sql
class come {
    static main(args) {
        def sql = Sql.newInstance("jdbc:mysql://localhost/test", "root","nayeem","com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
        assert(sql)
        sql.execute('drop table if exists  customers')
        sql.execute(
                '''create table customers(
                        CustomerID bigint(20) not null auto_increment,
                    CustomerName varchar(50) not null,
                        ContactName varchar(50) not null,
                        Address varchar(50) not null,
                        city varchar(25) not null,
                        PostalCode bigint(20) not null,
            Country varchar(20) not null,
            primary key(CustomerID))''')
        def i=1
        def key1= new XmlSlurper().parse('E:/kha.xml')
        assert(key1)
        //key1.each{println it}
        for (p in { vars -> customers 
        } ){
            println 'Hai'
            println("->$i")
            def CustomerID=p.CustomerID.text();
            println("->$CustomerID")
            def CustomerName=p.CustomerName.text();
            println("->$CustomerName")
            def ContactName=p.ContactName.text();
            println("->$ContactName")
            def Address=p.Address.text();
            println("->$Address")
            def array=[] as String
            def city=p.city.text();
            println("->$city")
            def PostalCode=p.PostalCode.text();
            println("->$PostalCode")
            def Country=p.Country.text();
            println("->$Country")
            def key2="insert into customers values($CustomerID,$CustomerName,$ContactName,$Address,$city,$PostalCode,$Country)"
            sql.execute(key2)
            i++
        }
        def list=sql.rows"select * from customers"
        println ''
        println '------reading data--------'
        println list
    }

}
```

i am getting  groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: CustomerID for class: come please give me reply

Comment: I don't want to be too critical but the code doesn't look nice to me (formatting, debug statements, hardcoded values, unused varaibles etc.). Anyway, have you thought about trying to do something like this: http://tugdualgrall.blogspot.com/2007/02/groovy-101-importing-xml-in-your.html